# MATLAB errorbar graph multiple set of data in one graph, how to change the color

Tags: matlab, errorbar

I am trying to plot different data set into the graph with errorbar. I don't know how to put different color to each set of data. And I am wondering if I can use 2D array to plot the graph, instead of using loop and loop thru each set of data. Thank you very much for help

My code:

```
y = [1 3 5;2 4 6];
e = [0.1 0.1 0.1;0.5 0.5 0.5];
x = [10 20 30];

for i = 1:2
    errorbar(x,y(i,:),e(i,:),'.')
    hold on;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure all inputs are of the same size - then you can plot them with a single command. By transposing the inputs you can also control which bars should be of the same colour (i.e. either across rows, or across columns of your original dataset).

```
y = [1 3 5;2 4 6];
e = [0.1 0.1 0.1;0.5 0.5 0.5];
x = [10 20 30];

hBars = errorbar([x;x]', y', e', '.');
```

You can then change the colours using the bar plot handle if you don't like the default ones, e.g.

```
set(hBars, {'Color'}, {'k';'g'});
```

Note that in order to change colours of both plots using a single `set` command, you should wrap the property name and property values in cell arrays, and the dimensions of property values should match those of the graphics handles.